# Absolute path information is required

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net

I am trying to migrate a .NET application from the old server to the new server. But, when i try to run it, it is giving me a weird error. This application is running fine in the old server though. I dont know what configuration has to be changed to be able to run this application. The stack trace for the error is this.`[ArgumentException: Absolute path information is required.]
   System.Security.Util.StringExpressionSet.CreateListFromExpressions(String[] str, Boolean needFullPath) +7494956
   System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission.AddPathList(FileIOPermissionAccess access, AccessControlActions control, String[] pathListOrig, Boolean checkForDuplicates, Boolean needFullPath, Boolean copyPathList) +87
   System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission..ctor(FileIOPermissionAccess access, String path) +65
   Microsoft.VisualBasic.Logging.FileLogTraceListener.DemandWritePermission() +69
   Microsoft.VisualBasic.Logging.FileLogTraceListener.set_Append(Boolean value) +17
   TE.Twain.RAT.Framework.Logger.LogFactory.Init(String lPath) in C:\Vivek\Rat_Checkout\Development\RAT\Framework\Logger\Logging.vb:51
   TE.Twain.RAT.Framework.Core.FrontController.Init(NameValueCollection lProperties) in C:\Vivek\Rat_Checkout\Development\RAT\Framework\Core\FrontController.vb:37
   TE.Twain.RAT.Web.GlobalApplication.Application_Start(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Vivek\Rat_Checkout\Development\RAT\Web\Global.asax.vb:34`

`[HttpException (0x80004005): Absolute path information is required.]
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.EnsureAppStartCalledForIntegratedMode(HttpContext context, HttpApplication app) +2761626
   System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +128
   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +188
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +295
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetPipelineApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +56
   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext) +231`

`[HttpException (0x80004005): Absolute path information is required.]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +8993587
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +85
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +333`

What could have possibly gone wrong?

Comment: did you check the .net version  between those two server?

Answer (score 0):

Check your Global.asax file line 34 for some type of file reference.

> C:\Vivek\Rat_Checkout\Development\RAT\Web\Global.asax.vb:34